# Verificar se um processo não está rodando para então executá-lo no Windows

Tags: processo

gostaria de verificar se um processo está ativo no windows e caso não executá-lo automaticamente, pois é um servidor dedicado e cai as vezes.

Pensei em rodar o script de tempo em tempo no agendador.

o nome do processo é servertet.exe

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Pensando na solução do seu problema, recomendo executar o aplicativo como serviço do windows, dessa forma você pode configurar para iniciar automaticamente, e se caso sua aplicação venha a cair mesmo com o servidor ligado, o serviço do windows cuida para reinicialo.

Assim, o uma das opções é o NSSM http://nssm.cc/usage.

Baixe o aplicativo do site acima (é Free) e coloque na mesma pasta do seu exe.

Em seguida entre no console do windows (cmd), vá até a pasta que baixou o arquivo e digite:

```
nssm install servertet
```

Será aberta uma janela para informar os parâmetros do serviço, informe os dados:

No campo Path, localize o arquivo servertet.exe

No campo StartupDirectory deixe do jeito que ele preencheu, caso queira (e saiba), pode preencher os demais campos das outras abas.

Clique em InstallService e o serviço será instalado.

A partir deste momento servertet passa ser controlada como um serviço do windows normalmente.

OBS.: Lembre-se de fechar o servertet.exe e iniciar como serviço do windows, e teste antes de colocar em produção.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida amigo!
Vou tentar esse método, até pq o server roda através de um arquivo bat.

Comment: Deu certo? Se sim, poderia marcar a pergunta como respondida? Na dúvida, visite o [tour] para saber como fazer isso. Obrigado.